# Dozer issue with ear file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, dozer

I m newbie in Spring mvc.I am using dozer in my application.when i work with local, am getting the result list.but when i build using jenkins that ear file showing the error.not showing the result list.any help appreciated

Comment: please show your code and tell more about the error you're getting.

Comment: @A4L Unknown error occurred: Class mapping not found by map-id: SRC-CLASS company DST-CLASS-> company MAP-ID-> company.This is the error i m getting when deploy the ear file in websphere application server.